# Starting a new task inside a function can crash a program?

Tags: c#

I have a function that is called by several GUI components, and always needs to be run in a different Task.
Is there a difference between doing it in this way each time:

```
public int foo()
{
   // do what you need to do
   return 1;
}

...
var t = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>foo());
```

and starting the task inside the foo function?

```
public int foo()
{
   var t = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
       // do what you need to do
       return 1;
   });
}

...
foo();
```

I get `System.AggregateException`  in this program, and I'm starting to think that the second way to start the task is a wrong one.

Comment: The second example won't compile because the function expects a return value. Please provide more complete code examples of how you are calling those functions. Also post the full exception stack trace.

Comment: What exceptions are inside your AggregateException? It just groups up the exceptions that are thrown by your task and its children. Without knowing the exceptions contained inside, it's hard to guess why your program is failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the InnerException. The [`AggregateException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) is used to bundle up exceptions caused by Tasks/PLinq. More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx

> AggregateException is used to
>   consolidate multiple failures into a
>   single, throwable exception object. It
>   is used extensively in the Task
>   Parallel Library and Parallel LINQ
>   (PLINQ). For an example, see How to:
>   Handle Exceptions Thrown by Tasks and
>   How to: Handle Exceptions in a PLINQ
>   Query.

Worth also reading [How to: Handle Exceptions Thrown by Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614.aspx)